# Draw formgroup in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to draw HTML of form has nested sections according to data come from server with no predefind number of nested sections
as below

```
{
  "structure": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Section 1",
      "structure": [
        {
          "id": "1_1",
          "title": "section 1_1",
          "structure": [
            {
              "id": "1_1_1",
              "title": "section 1_1_1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "1_2",
          "title": "section 1_2",
          "structure": [
            {
              "id": "1_2_1",
              "title": "section 1_2_1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "section 2",
      "structure": [
        {
          "id": "2_1",
          "title": "section 2_1",
          "structure": [
            {
              "id": "2_1_1",
              "title": "section 2_1_1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2_2",
          "title": "section 2_2",
          "structure": [
            {
              "id": "2_2_1",
              "title": "section 2_2_1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="subjectForm">
  <div formArrayName="structure">
    <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="
        sectionDetails;
        context: {
          sectionIndex: sectionIndex,
          sectionForm: subjectForm.controls.structure.controls[sectionIndex]
        }
      "
    ></ng-container>
    <ng-template
      #sectionDetails
      let-tempSectionIndex="sectionIndex"
      let-tempSectionForm="sectionForm"
    >
      <div [formGroupName]="tempSectionIndex">
        <input
          type="text"
          nbInput
          formControlName="title"
          status="info"
          placeholder="Section titless"
        />
        <div formArrayName="structure">
          <ng-container
            *ngFor="
              let form of tempSectionForm.controls.structure.controls;
              let i = index
            "
          >
            <ng-container
              *ngTemplateOutlet="
                sectionDetails;
                context: {
                  sectionIndex: i,
                  sectionForm: tempSectionForm.controls.structure.controls[i]
                }
              "
            ></ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</form>
```

formgroup created well in component.ts but i have problem of drawing the formgroup in HTML,
the issue is child sections are not drawn as in order as expected 
e.g. 
section 1_1 appeared in place of section 1_1_1 ...etc

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.subjectService.createSubjectForm(this, this.subject);
}
```

formService.js

```
createSubjectForm(scope, subject) {
    scope.subjectForm = this.fb.group({
      'path': [[]],
    });
    if (subject.subjectFormatSubjects)
      this.createSectionForm(scope.subjectForm.controls, subject.subjectFormatSubjects.data)
  }
  createSectionForm(formPath, sections) {
    if (!formPath['structure'])
      formPath['structure'] = this.fb.array([]);
    sections.forEach((section) => {
      (<FormArray>formPath['structure'].controls).push(this.fb.group({
        'title': [section.title, Validators.required]
      }));
      const sectionIndex = formPath['structure'].controls.length - 1;
      formPath['structure'].controls[sectionIndex].controls['path'] = this.fb.control([...formPath.path.value, sectionIndex]);
      if (section.subjectFormatSubjects) {
        this.createSectionForm(formPath['structure'].controls[sectionIndex].controls, section.subjectFormatSubjects.data);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What is your actual requirement ?

Comment: Share your example-component.ts file and let us see how did you create the tempSectionForm. Maybe use Reactive Forms? You could use them and after getting data from the server set it's values using result. I'm not sure about the performance. Take a look here if you don't know reactiveforms https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/basics-reactive-forms-in-angular/ 
There is also npm package helping create a form out of json https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular6-json-schema-form

Comment: In your form structure in section 2 there are groups with same name . That may cause some errors when creating FormGroups or in html. If you provide some .ts maybe we can help you.

Comment: @Adam i already use reactive form pleas take a look on component.ts and the service

Comment: @h4ckthepl4net
it is miss typo i corrected pleas take a look on component.ts and the service